# No wifi adapter found Ubuntu 18.04 Dell Studio 1537

Tags: dell

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a dell studio 1537 after getting continued charging errors after upgrading to windows 10 pro from windows 7 pro. The battery would not charge regardless of the troubleshooting steps I took. I am getting the no wifi adapter found error after installing Ubuntu as well as continued charging errors. I searched numerous google and Youtube posts supposedly providing the fix, but none of them have resolved the issue. I am new to the OS and wanted to begin learning how to work with it but the issues have me baffled. Can you help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve the "Wireless Adapter not Found' problem.

**Step 1**: Identify your exact wireless device.

Many computers are sold with various wireless devices installed. Not every Lenovo T440p, as an example, has the same exact device. Some were sold With Intels, some with Atheros and so forth. To determine what exact device your computer has, let's ask it! Please open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t and run:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Also run:

```
rfkill list all
```

The first command will tell us the exact identity of your installed wireless device. The second will tell us if the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable the otherwise working wireless.

Here is an example of the output from the first command:

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek semiconductor co., Ltd. RTL 8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
        Subsystem Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
```

The crucial bit of information is the pci.id here: 10ec:c821.

When you find yours, next run:

```
uname -r
```

That command will tell you the kernel version you are running. We need to know that because the method to install a driver varies by kernel version. In other words, the method used in kernel 3.xx is different from 4.xx which is, in turn, different from 5.xx.

**Step 2**: Using these two data points, search Ask Ubuntu for the pci.id; 10ec:c821 in my example. Almost no matter what device you find that you have, someone else has it, too, and we've answered with a method to install the driver. Try to find an answer that involves your same kernel version or Ubuntu version (16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, 19.10, etc.).

Finally, if you get stuck, tell us your details in an edit to your question and we'll be happy to help.